# Python PDFkit shrinking HTML and not displaying numbers correctly

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, python-2.7, pdfkit

I have a local html file created with Jinja2 that I am trying to export as a PDF. The HTML in my browser looks correct ([click here](https://pasteboard.co/HPqDHRp.jpg) for a screenshot), however, when exporting with pdfkit, it seems like the entire document is shrinking and the text is jumbled (Mostly the numbers).

My pdf output can be found [here.](https://docdro.id/XSO9fGN)

My python code is as follows:

```
import pdfkit
import os
import sys

path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
options = {
         'dpi': 300,
         'page-size': 'Letter',
         'margin-top': '0.25in',
         'margin-right': '0.25in',
         'margin-bottom': '0.25in',
         'margin-left': '0.25in',
         'encoding': "UTF-8",
         'custom-header' : [
            ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
         ],
         'no-outline': None
    }
pdfkit.from_file('brochure.html','brochure.pdf', configuration = config, options= options)
```

My HTML and CSS file is as follows (some text was changed for privacy and `@fontface` not shown in CSS):

```css
@media print {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
 @page
 {
  width: 8.5in;
   height: 11in;
  margin: 0.25in;
 }
 body{
  margin: 0.25in;
 }

}


body, div, dl, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, pre, code, blockquote {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border-width:0;
}
body {
 margin: 0.25in;
 width: 8.5in;
 height: 11in;

}
/* Begin Header */

header{
 width: 8in;
 height: 1in;
 background-image: url("../Pics/header-bg.JPG")!important;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper{
 margin: 0.25in;
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100%;
}

#head_desc{
 width: 1.9in;
 height: 100%;
 display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#head_desc h2{
  padding: 8% 4% 0% 8%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  color:white;
  font-family:"Gotham Narrow Medium", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:19px;
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:500;
  transform: scale(1, .9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, .9);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, .9);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, .9);
    -o-transform: scale(1, .9);
}

#head_desc p{
 padding: 0% 4% 0% 8%;
  margin-top: 0px;
 color: white;
 font-family: "Gotham Narrow Light", sans-serif;
 /* text-transform: uppercase; */
 font-size: 17px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 transform: scale(1, .9);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1, .9);
}
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#head_address{
 display: inline-block;
 float:right;
 text-align: right;
 height: 100%;
 width: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#head_address h1{
 padding: 4% 4% 0% 8%;
  margin-top: 0px;
 font-family:"Gotham Narrow Light";
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #c10230;
 font-style:normal;
 transform: scale(1, .9);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1, .9);
 font-weight:500;
}

#head_address h2{
 padding: 0% 4% 0% 8%;
 font-family:"Gotham Narrow Light";
 font-size: 19px;
 color: #c10230;
 font-style:normal;
 transform: scale(1, .9);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1, .9);
 font-weight:500;
}

.images{
 width: 100%;
 height: 4.8in;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 1%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.hero-image{
 width:64%;
 float:left;
 display: inline-block;
}
.second-image, .third-image{
 display: inline-block;
 /* width: 34%;
 height: 48%; */
 float: right;
}

.third-image{
 margin-top: 1.5%;
}

.fillwidth {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.fillheight {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}


.trailerleft {
 overflow: hidden;
  width: 64.5%;
  height: 100%;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
}

.trailerright {
 overflow: hidden;
  width: 34%;
  height: 48.7%;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
}

/* .fill{
 display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden
}

.fill img {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
  min-height: auto;
} */

#greybar{
 width: 5.4in;
 height: 0.3in;
 float: right;
 background-color:#6d6e71;
 border-width:0px;
}

#pspecs{
 color:white;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 4%;
 margin-top: 0.5%;
 font-family: "Gotham Narrow Book";
 transform: scale(1, .9);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1, .9);
 font-size: 20px;
}

#contact-section{
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 width: 1.8333in;
 font-size: 10px;
 margin-top: 10%;
}

.moreinfo{
 font-family: "Gotham Rounded Light Italic";
 font-size: 11px;
 margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.contact-info{
 margin-top:4%;
}

.name{
 font-family: "Gotham Narrow Book";
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #c10230;
 font-size: 11px;
}
.title{
 font-family: "Gotham Rounded Book Italic";
 color: black;
}

.phone,.email{
 font-family: "Gotham Rounded Book";
}

.con-address{
 margin-top: 10%;
 font-family: "Gotham Rounded Book";
 font-size: 9px;
}

.con-address span{
 font-family: "Gotham Narrow Book";
 font-size: 11px;
}
.disclaimer{
 font-family: "Gotham Rounded Light";
 margin-top: 8%;
 font-size: 9px;
}

#propertyinfo{
 float: right;
 width: 5.3in;
 margin-top: 1%;
}

#pitable{
 width: 100%;
}




.leftcell{
 color: #c10230;
 font-family: "Gotham Rounded Book", sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-style: normal;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-weight: 300;
 width: 35%;
 padding: 2%;
 border-bottom: solid black .5px;
}



.rightcell{
 color: #000000;
 font-family: "Gotham Rounded Book", sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding: 2% 0% 2% 0%;
 border-bottom: solid black .5px;
}

.rightcell.comments, .leftcell.comments{
 border-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.rightcell ul{
 padding-left: 5%;
  margin: 0;
}

footer{
 position:absolute;
 height: 0.52in;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
}
.footerimage{
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
}
.footerimage img{
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 float: right;
}
.footerline{
 margin-top:.4%;
 margin-bottom:.2%;
 height: .5%;
 border-top: .3px solid #58585b;
}
#footerlink{
 float:right;
 height: .5%;
 font-family: "Gotham Narrow Book";
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #c10230;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Off-Market-Template</title>
  <link href="./css/idGeneratedStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./js/script.js" />
  </script>
</head>

<body id="offmarketbrochure-template" lang="en-US">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div id="head_desc">
        <h2>Off-market</h2>
        <p>Confidential </br> Sale Offering</p>
      </div>
      <div id="head_address">
        <h1>Test Address</h1>
        <h2>Chicago IL, 60607</h2>
      </div>
    </header>


    <div class="images">
      <div class="hero-image trailerleft">
        <img src="./Pics/image1.jpg" alt="" class="fillheight" />
      </div>
      <div class="second-image trailerright">
        <img src="./Pics/streetview.jpg" alt="" class="fillwidth" />
      </div>
      <div class="third-image trailerright">
        <img src="./Pics/mapview.png" alt="" class="fillheight" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="greybar" class="Basic-Graphics-Frame _idGenObjectStyleOverride-2">
      <p id="pspecs">
        Property Specifications
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="contact-section">
      <p class="moreinfo">
        For more information, please contact:
      </p>

      
      <div class="contact-info">
        <h3 class="name">BROKER 1, SIOR</h3>
        <p class="title">Principal</p>
        <p class="phone">312-111-1111</p>
        <p class="email">BROKER EMAIL</p>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="contact-info">
        <h3 class="name">BROKER 2</h3>
        <p class="title">Principal</p>
        <p class="phone">312-111-1111</p>
        <p class="email">BROKER EMAIL</p>
      </div>
      
      
      <p class="con-address">
        <span>Company <br /></span>
        Address <br />
        Chicago, IL 
      </p>
      <p class="disclaimer">
        All information contained herein is from sources deemed reliable and is submitted subject to errors, omissions and to change of price or terms without notice.
      </p>

    </div>
    <div id="propertyinfo">
      <table id="pitable" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
          <!-- Max amount of rows not including comments should be 8 -->
          <!-- Building Size Row -->
          
          
          
          <tr>
            <td class="leftcell">
              Building Size
            </td>
            <td class="rightcell">
              28,106 SF
            </td>
          </tr>
          

          <!-- Land Size Row -->
          
          
          <tr>
            <td class="leftcell">
              Land Size
            </td>
            <td class="rightcell">
              17,860 SF
            </td>
          </tr>
          

          <!-- Stories Row -->
          
          
          <tr>
            <td class="leftcell">
              Stories
            </td>
            <td class="rightcell">
              3
            </td>
          </tr>
          

          <!-- Drive in Row -->
          

          <!-- Docks Row -->
          
          
          <tr>
            <td class="leftcell">
              Loading Docks
            </td>
            <td class="rightcell">
              4 ext
            </td>
          </tr>
          

          <!-- Construction Row -->
          
          
          <tr>
            <td class="leftcell">
              Construction
            </td>
            <td class="rightcell">
              Masonry
            </td>
          </tr>
          

          <!-- Ceiling Height Row -->
          
          
          <tr>
            <td class="leftcell">
              Ceiling Height
            </td>
            <td class="rightcell">
              12'
            </td>
          </tr>
          

          <!-- Elevators Row -->
          <!--  -->

          <!-- Cranes Row -->
          <!-- 
          
          <tr>
            <td class="leftcell">
              Cranes
            </td>
            <td class="rightcell">
              None
            </td>
          </tr>
           -->

          <!-- Power Row -->
          <!--  -->

          <!-- Parking Row -->
          <!-- 
          
          <tr>
            <td class="leftcell">
              Parking
            </td>
            <td class="rightcell">
              8 free Surface Spaces are available; Ratio of 0.28/1,000 SF
            </td>
          </tr>
           -->

          <!-- Ward Row -->
          

          <!-- Zoning Row -->
          
            
            <tr>
              <td class="leftcell">
                Zoning
              </td>
              <td class="rightcell">
                C1-3
              </td>
            </tr>
          

          <!-- Taxes Row -->
          
          
          <tr>
            <td class="leftcell">
              2017 Taxes
            </td>
            <td class="rightcell">
              $46,266.56
            </td>
          </tr>
          

          <!-- Pins Row -->
          


          <!-- Sale Row -->
          
          
          <tr>
            <td class="leftcell">
              Sale Price
            </td>
            <td class="rightcell">
              $2,000,000
            </td>
          </tr>
          


          <!-- lease Row -->
          

          <!-- Comments section -->
          <tr>
            <td class="leftcell comments">
              Comments
            </td>
            <td class="rightcell comments">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <p>
                    Easily accessible via Ashland Station (Green, Pink Lines), located 0.5 miles away
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p>
                    Located 1.0 miles from the Chicago Ogilvie Transportation Center Commuter station
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p>
                    Excellent location on W Randolph Street
                  </p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>


    </div>
    <footer>

      <div class="footerimage">
        <img src="./Pics/footerlogo.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="footerline">

      </div>
      <p id="footerlink">
        www.Website.com
      </p>
    </footer>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much for your assistance!

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case adjusting the dpi in the pdfkit options did the trick:

```py
options = {
    'dpi': 300 # adjust till it fits (try like 250 or 350)
}

pdfkit.from_file('a.html', 'a.pdf', options = options)
```